# AWS cloudfront invalidation with OriginPath

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront setup with OriginPath so that the path can be updated to point to a new folder in the corresponding S3 static website bucket.

For e.g. www.foo.net with Origin path "0.0.1" will be rendered from bucket www.foo.net/0.0.1.
Now let's say I have new assets created under www.foo.net/0.0.2 and I update my OriginPath in the C/F distribution to 0.0.2 using UpdateDistribution, how would I invalidate the previous cloudfront distribution ? Specifically, in my CreateInvalidation() call, what should Paths.Items be ? Should it be "/*" or "/0.0.1/*" or "/0.0.2/*" ?

Answer (score 1):

The invalidation path would be the path as requested by the browser, so use `/*`.

The Origin Path isn't prepended until after the cache has been checked, so the modified path wouldn't be included in the cache key.